Open3D can't call function 'read_point_cloud'/Module 'Open3D' has no attribute 'read_point_cloud'
So I cloned a git repository which is registrating point clouds using probabilistic methods such as GMMs (Gaussian-Mixture-Models) but also incorporates Open3D. Because the registration is running on the GPU instead of the CPU I needed to install CUDA. Mainly because the repository imports the CuPy-Package which in turn also requires CUDA. Because I had some problems installing and building the latest versions of CuPy, I solved it by just using an older version, in my case version 10.2, which seems to run on my computer and on my GPU (it's a GTX 1050). After that CuPy was successfully imported into the project. Installation and import of Open3D worked also fine. However, after running a python test-file which is registering two point clouds, I got a weird error message in the terminal, which also crashed the program. It says Module 'Open3D' has no attribute 'read_point_cloud'
The corressponding code line is this: source = o3.read_point_cloud(filepath) Now, I made some research by reading the Open3D documentation and I found out that read_point_cloud is an already provided default method in the Open3D library, in older versions, as well as in its current version 0.18.0. It is also the same version which I installed via pip previously. Could it somehow be related to the CUDA problem I described above or am I missing something here?

What about this? https://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.io.read_point_cloud.html

@ewokx You mean I should just add an 'io' after the 'o3', but before the 'read_point_cloud(filepath)'? Because that's what the documentation you've sent me says. In the original authors code (it's not my code) there is no 'io', but the last commit is already 5 years old, which means nobody was working on the repository since and thus they were using an older version of Open3D back then?

The thing with copying code from others is that you need to ensure you're either using the same version of the library or you use the newest library but adapt the code.  So you should have source = o3.io.read_point_cloud(filepath); that is assuming you did import Open3D as o3.

The right way to load a pointcloud is to use either

open3d.io.read_point_cloud(filepath) if using legacy API which returns open3d.geometry.PointCloud, or
open3d.t.io.read_point_cloud(filepath) if using tensor API which returns open3d.t.geometry.PointCloud.

The t stands for tensor, which supports use of cuda. The legacy API used eigen which didnt support computation on gpu, hence led to the development of tensor based api.
Furthermore, you can check Multi-Scale ICP on CUDA, to do registration on gpu. It does not provide GMM but can be a good start.

Can you share the link to the repository you used for registration using GMM

Sorry for my late reply and thank you for your answer! I tried to modify the code according to your answer but now I'm facing another issue. After changing the line into open3d.io.read_point_cloud(filepath), the next code line which is source = o3.voxel_down_sample(source, voxel_size=voxel) throws the error module open3d has no attribute voxel_down_sample. According to open3Ds latest documentation you have to call open3d.geometry.voxel_down_sample. I did that but then I got this error message module open3d.cpu.pybind.geometry has no attribute voxel_down_sample.

@Ozymandias All I can say is first go through tutorials properly. The code you are using is too old to be used now. For a pointcloud, you should use pcd.voxel_down_sample, where pcd is the pointcloud object you got. Consult official documentation of v0.18.0 https://www.open3d.org/docs/release/search.html?q=voxel_down_sample&check_keywords=yes&area=default
Try to go through open3d tutorials here https://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/ and see my recent answers which mainly focus on open3d - https://stackoverflow.com/users/1874627/saurabheights?tab=answers&sort=newest

Here is the link to the GMM-based registration repository: https://github.com/somanshu25/GPU-Accelerated-Point-Cloud-Registration-Using-Hierarchical-GMM I cloned their repository and actually I just wanted to run their demo code which is the python file run_gmm_static.py. According to the author's README you just have to run it to see the GMM-based registration of a bunny pointcloud. But I can't do it because of the issues I mentioned above. Maybe I should build Open3D version 0.7.0? Because that's what they are using. However, pip can't find it.

@Ozymandias My advise. Stick to v0.18.0. The code in the file run_gmm_static is not big and can be easily updated to work with latest version. It should hardly take a few hours to maybe 2-3 days for you to learn how open3d works.

Hmm okay, so I assume you have taken a look at it and you suggest to adjust the code in the run_gmm_static.py file? But what about the rest of the repository? Do I need to change all that too or is this one file enough? Actually I wanted to start working in Open3D but my supervisor adviced against it (it's an university project) because he says Open3D is too slow. Thus he suggested to look for alternative approaches such as GMMs, which is why I ended up here. So am I supposed to adjust th entire repository or just this one file`? Or should I maybe stick with classic Open3D?

@Ozymandias - I wont be able to read the whole repo due to time bounds, but as far as I understand, the code of this repo uses cupy and other libs to do most processing on gpu and open3d is mainly for loading pointcloud and visualization. For example see line 30 which extracts points into a numpy array and thus doesnt uses numpy afterwards until its time for visualization.
Regarding your supervisor comment - The library is still not mature, for example it has DBScan clustering which is not yet supported on GPU, but a lot of parts of library is highly optimized for CPU and GPU.

So your advice is to use classic Open3D and give it a chance? Or at least using multi-scale ICP on CUDA (the first link that you've sent me)? I also found this library called 'probreg' https://github.com/neka-nat/probreg My supervisor also suggested to look into it. Do you know something about this 'probreg'-library? It seems to be newer (last commit was 2 weeks ago) and it also supports probabilistic point cloud registration methods such as Coherent Point Drift and GMMs.

My suggestion - 1. Update code of run_gmm_static to work with Open3d 0.18.0 and try to run it. 2. Run MultiScaleIcp on CPU/CUDA (this should take 1-2 hours, just follow tutorial to see how well it works for you) 3. Probreg looks nice, uses latest open3d version, but I haven't used it.
